# @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises and new Promise(() => return resolve())

Tags: firebase, promise, async-await, es6-promise, typescript-eslint

I have a Promise(() => return resolve()) pattern in a function I got from [firebase functions samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/google-sheet-sync/functions/index.js).

```
const appendPromise = (requestWithoutAuth: {
  spreadsheetId: any
  range: string
  valueInputOption: string
  insertDataOption: string
  resource: { values: any[][] }
}): Promise<any> => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return getAuthorizedClient().then((client) => {
      const sheets = google.sheets('v4')
      const request = requestWithoutAuth
      request.auth = client
      return sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(request, (err: any, response: { data: unknown }) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`The API returned an error: ${err}`)
          return reject(err)
        }
        return resolve(response.data)
      })
    })
  })
}
```

eslint complains about [@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-misused-promises.md).

I'm not used to that, is it enough to replace new Promise() by Promise.resolve() ?

Thanks

Comment: You can't replace it with Promise.resolve, because you don't have the value to resolve with until inside the callback. But getAuthorizedClient *already seems to return a promise*, so it's not clear why you've wrapped that in a new Promise.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the linter's problem is that you use a Promise *inside* a Promise constructor. Use an async function and move the Promise constructor one indentation lower:

```
const appendPromise = async (requestWithoutAuth: {
  spreadsheetId: any
  range: string
  valueInputOption: string
  insertDataOption: string
  resource: { values: any[][] }
}): Promise<any> => {
  const client = await getAuthorizedClient();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const sheets = google.sheets('v4')
      const request = requestWithoutAuth
      request.auth = client
      return sheets.spreadsheets.values.append(request, (err: any, response: { data: unknown }) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`The API returned an error: ${err}`)
          return reject(err)
        }
        return resolve(response.data)
      })
  })
}
```